# Cannot access JSON Properties within an HTTP POST Response

Tags: javascript, json, post, xmlhttprequest

I am calling an HTTP POST Request, the response is JSON data.

POST Request:

```
const postXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
postXHR.open('POST', postOptions);
postXHR.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/json");
postXHR.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/json");
postXHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
    const response = postXHR.response;
    if (response.response) {
        console.log(postXHR.status);
    }
    createNewOptionValues(response);
}
postXHR.send('{"optionName":"optionName46", "platformName":"platformName46","dotDigitalId":3,"googleId":4}');
```

POST Response/JSON Data:

```
{
    "data": {
        "rooftopGoogleOptionId": 99,
        "googleId": 4,
        "dotDigitalId": 3,
        "optionName": "optionName46",
        "optionValue": null,
        "platformName": "platformName46",
        "googleAccount": null,
        "dotDigitalAccount": null,
        "updatedBy": null,
        "updatedAt": null,
        "createdBy": "root",
    },
    "status": 201,
    "message": "success"
}
```

The createNewOptionValue function should log the value of a property within the response.

```
function createNewOptionValues(obj){
    console.log(obj.googleId);
    console.log(obj['googleId']);
}
```

Yet, the output is undefined, when using console.log(obj), the response does show.

Comment: You need to call `JSON.parse()` to conver the JSON to an object.

Comment: It was throwing error "unexpected end of json input" until I added .data after obj and before .googleId

Comment: Neither of those should affect whether `JSON.parse()` works.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, I'm just letting you know simply adding JSON.parse(obj.googleId) to the code, did not solve the issue, instead an error was thrown, the error went away when .data was included as JSON.parse(obj.data.googleId);

Comment: It should be `JSON.parse(obj)`.

Answer (score 1):

When you receive a response, it is in "text" format (in most of the cases)
So you need to pass that response to JSON.parse for accessing it as a JSON Object.

Adding just 1 line in your **createNewOptionValues** function will make it work. Also, you need to access obj.data.googleId instead of accessing obj.googleId

```
function createNewOptionValues(obj){
    obj = JSON.parse(obj)
    console.log(obj.data.googleId);
    console.log(obj.data['googleId']);
}
```